# Order rows in descendig order by overall column in gtsummary not working on RMarkdown?

Tags: r, gtsummary

My dataset looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
  NOME_MUNICIPIO = sample(c("Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo", "Araruama", "Queimados"), 230, replace = TRUE)
)
```

When I use gtsummary to order in descending order by the overall column in RStudio, it works perfectly.

```
    data %>%
  select(anoobito, NOME_MUNICIPIO) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = anoobito,
              label = c(NOME_MUNICIPIO ~ "")) %>%
  add_overall(last = T) %>%
  modify_table_body(fun = ~ dplyr::arrange(., desc(readr::parse_number(stat_0)))) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1":"stat_5") ~ "**Ano do Óbito**") %>%
  modify_header(label = 'Município de Residência') %>%
  bold_labels()
```

[image]

The issue is when I run the same command on RMarkdown. It doesn't order by descending order. I'm using the same command for other tables and it works perfectly.

This is the result table I got from my original dataset:

[image]

But there's a row that it's overall (Total) value is over 8k obs, and it should be the first row in the table. I have no idea why that's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second output table in your question shows that you are using `.` as a `big.mark`/ thousand divider, i.e. last column “N = 9.150”.
`readr::parse_numbers()` by default expects `,` as a thousand divider and will
parse a `.` as the decimal mark.

```r
library(tidyverse)

parse_number("9.150")
#> [1] 9.15
```

We can change that by defining setting `decimal_mark` to `,` in the locale
argument.

```r
readr::parse_number("9.150", locale = readr::locale(decimal_mark = ","))
#> [1] 9150
```

I changed your example data, so we have totals above 1000 while Rio the Janeiro
will stay below 1000.

```r
data <- data.frame(
  anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
  NOME_MUNICIPIO = sample(
    c("Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo", "Araruama", "Queimados"),
    230000,
    prob = c(.01, 1, 1, 1),
    replace = TRUE
  )
)

library(gtsummary)
theme_gtsummary_language("en", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
```

If we use your original code Rio de Janeiro comes first, since its total
value is parsed as higher than the values of the other places.

```r
data %>%
  select(anoobito, NOME_MUNICIPIO) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = anoobito,
              label = c(NOME_MUNICIPIO ~ "")) %>%
  add_overall(last = T) %>%
  modify_table_body(fun = ~ arrange(., desc(parse_number(stat_0))))
```

[image]

We get the desired row order when we include `locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")`
in the `parse_number()` call.

```r
data %>%
  select(anoobito, NOME_MUNICIPIO) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = anoobito,
              label = c(NOME_MUNICIPIO ~ "")) %>%
  add_overall(last = T) %>%
  modify_table_body(fun = ~ arrange(., desc(parse_number(
    stat_0, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")
  ))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Till is great. Here is another version that doesn't use `modify_table_body()`, which I sometime find somewhat simpler. Happy Programming!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'
# set language to "pt"
theme_gtsummary_language("pt", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
#> Setting theme `language: pt`

# simulate data
data <- 
  data.frame(
    anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
    NOME_MUNICIPIO = sample(c("Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo", "Araruama", "Queimados"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
  )


tbl <-
  data |> 
  # build primary summary table
  tbl_summary(
    by = anoobito, 
    sort = list(NOME_MUNICIPIO = "frequency")
  ) |> 
  # add spanning header to the years
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Ano do Óbito**") |> 
  # add an overall column
  add_overall() |> 
  # udpate the headers, and put the Ns on a new line
  modify_header(label = '**Município de Residência**',
                all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**  \n N = {style_number(n)}") |> 
  # we don't want the header row, so remove it and undo the indentation
  remove_row_type(type = "header") |> 
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = label,
    text_format = "indent",
    undo_text_format = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>